# Using llama index but avoiding the tiktoken API call

Tags: python, nlp, large-language-model, llama-index, retrieval-augmented-generation

I want to use `llama_index` but when I import the package I get the following error

```
ConnectionError: ('Connected aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))
```

This is because `llama_index` makes a request via the package tiktoken by open ai. You can see this in line 55.
https://github.com/run-llama/llama_index/blob/main/llama_index/utils.py#L52

Which at the end makes a call to this API (https://openaipublic.blob.core.windows.net/gpt-2/encodings/main/vocab.bpe)
https://github.com/openai/tiktoken/blob/main/tiktoken_ext/openai_public.py#L11

Is there a way to avoid this API call? And just maybe have it locally? I can't access the internet in the environment I'm working in so I can't make API calls.

Comment: using `llama localhost` in Google I found: [cocktailpeanut/dalai: The simplest way to run LLaMA on your local machine](https://github.com/cocktailpeanut/dalai). But for some models it may need even `~32 GB RAM` and `disk 432.64GB` - so you may need fast and expensive computer to run it locally.

Comment: This is not llama_index, this is llama which is an LLM.

Comment: I think problem can be the same. It may need fast and expensive computer to run it locally. Besides it may need to rewrite many code to work with local code. So it could be hard work.